# Are Dead Island's achievements counted across playthroughs and play modes?

Tags: achievements, dead-island

I want to know if the achievements can be acquired across multiplayer playthroughs/characters and through singleplayer and co-op.

I'm mostly wondering because the achievement **Busy, busy, busy** says "Finish 75 quests cumulatively," but the other achievements do not have this caveat.

So for example, for the achievement **Cardio**, which requires traveling 250 kilometers on foot, will that add up when I'm playing single player as Xian *and* when playing co-op as Logan, or not? Do all achievements work the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Most achievements and challenges are cumulative across all playthroughs and modes. 
The achievements relating to collectibles (Gotta find 'em all and Nearly there) seem to require using a single character, but you can repeat the campaign with a character in single-player mode, which keeps your skills and inventory intact, including all collectibles you've found, so you can use that game-plus to get the rest of the items you missed the first time through.

Also, the challenge relating to collectibles (My collectibles, let me show you them!) **does** count total collectibles across all characters, and they do **not** have to be unique collectibles. (Example: If you get Banoi Herald excerpt #1 with all four characters, that will count 4 toward the total of 140; you do not have to find 140 unique collectibles across all four characters.)

Note that this gives you an easy way to level up a new character: get to 90% or more on a Level 4 challenge with a high-level character, get to a checkpoint to save your progress, then load a low-level character and complete the challenge. Because the experience reward does not scale, a reward that might not change a level-50 character much can boost a level-5 character several levels.

Comment: ...I had no idea the collectibles didn't have to be unique. Huh.

Comment: yeah, I was pretty much expecting to wait until late in the next game to pop that one ... it was a total surprise to have it hit so early (and to have so many skill points to apply; I didn't understand what happened. I must have applied 3 before I realized).

Answer (score 2):

Cardio will count across all characters. So will the driving one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about all the achievements, but I recently got the Gesundheit! achievement (heal yourself 100 times with medkits) using a newly started character so at least some of them are across different characters.